# Using XSLT Absolute ResolvedURL as a link

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

I'm trying to pull links from my XML file and use them in an XSLT file. Here is the XML:

```
<ElementData type="LBarData">
 <ItemCount>5.0</ItemCount>
 <Items class="array">
  <LBarItem>
   <EventHandlers type="LinkEvents">
    <Click/>
    <MouseOut/>
    <MouseOver/>
   </EventHandlers>
   <IsPageNumber>0</IsPageNumber>
   <ResolvedURL>
    <Absolute>http://www4.uwm.edu/letsci/</Absolute>
    <ServerRelative>http://www4.uwm.edu/letsci/</ServerRelative>
   </ResolvedURL>
   <Title>College of Letters and Science</Title>
   <WantHighlight>0</WantHighlight>
  </LBarItem>
```

Below that are more instances of the "LBarItem" with similar data. I'm using the following to get the link "title":

```
<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
```

How to I pull the "ResolvedURL/Absolute" and use it as a link on the title?

**Desired output (from comments)**

> ```
> <a href="URL">Title</a>
> ```
>
> With URL being the XML
>   "ResolvedURL/Absolute" and Title being
>   the XML "Title".

Comment: @user535332: What is the desired output?

Comment: <a href="URL">Title</a> with URL being the XML "ResolvedURL/Absolute" and Title being the XML "Title".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a FAQ,

**Use**:

```
<a href="{ResolvedURL/Absolute}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a>
```

**The technique of evaluating an XPath expression inside an attribute is a powerful, standard XSLT way of doing this, called [AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute-Value-Templates).